# "Run-time error '424': Object Required"

Tags: excel, vba, object, required

I want a function to take two parameters, a searching cell and a cell to search in, where the searching cell contains a comma separated list. I want each element to be tested to see if it is in the 'search in' cell. For example:

```
List_of_String: word1, word2, word3  
Where_to_Search: bbbbbword1 'Return TRUE'  
Where_to_Search: bbbbhhhhhmmmmm 'Return FALSE
```

I have written:

```
Function Search_in_String(List_of_Strings_to_Search As String, Where_to_Search As String)

String_array = Split(List_of_Strings_to_Search, ",")
Dim is_in_num As Integer
Dim is_in As Boolean

is_in = False

For i = 0 To (UBound(String_array) - 1)
    is_in_num = InStr(Where_to_Search, Trim(String_array(i)))
    If is_in_num > 0 Then is_in = True
    If is_in Then Exit For
Next i

Search_in_String = is_in
End Function



Sub test()
    MsgBox Search_in_String(BJ7.Value, Bk7.Value)
End Sub
```

The test() function I'm using to test my Search_in_String function (which I believe is also not working). When I step in (F8) I get the error:

> Run-Time error '424':
>   Object required

Comment: `BJ7` and `Bk7` are not objects. Put `Option Explicit` on top of your code module.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks. I've done that and am now getting `Variable not defined` with BJ7 and BK7. If change them to `Range("BJ7").Value` and `Range("BK7").Value`, I get `Type mismatch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the sub test() for this:

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox Search_in_String(Range("BJ7").Value, Range("BJ7").Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I've just tried doing that and I now get `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch`

Comment: On the line `MsgBox Search_in_String(Range("BK7").Value, Range("BJ7").Value)`

Comment: add to the function 'As Boolean'  
 Function Search_in_String(List_of_Strings_to_Search As String, Where_to_Search As String) As Boolean

Comment: Makes sense, but still getting the same error on the same line.

Comment: Make sure to declare all variables:   Dim String_array() As String
Dim i As Integer....Option Explicit

Function Search_in_String(List_of_Strings_to_Search As String, Where_to_Search As String) As Boolean

Dim String_array() As String
Dim i As Integer
......
End Function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92731/discussion-between-hugues-paquet-blanchette-and-pokeairguy).

Comment: Sorry, got distracted with something else. And my companies filter is blocking the chat feature so unable use that. That does seem to be working now! Thanks for your help